# JQuery - erro ao acessar array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, array

Preciso comparar duas arrays, uma com dias de um calendário e outra com dias cadastrados. Quando o dia cadastrado é correspondente ao valor da propriedade `innerHTML` do array de `div` ele deve pintar o background dessa `div` de preto:

HTML

```
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>

  ...

  <div class="item">31</div>
</div>

<div class="dias-cadastrados">
  <div class="day">4</div>
  <div class="day">21</div>

  ...
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var evento      = $(".day");
var eventos_arr = [];
var dias        = $(".item");

for (var i = 0; i < evento.length; i++) {

  eventos_arr[i] = evento[i].innerHTML;

  var count = eventos_arr[i];

  for (var y = 0; y < dias.length; y++) {

    dias[count].style.backgroundColor = "#000"; // output: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined 

  };

};
```

O algoritmo além de não fazer o que deveria retorna o erro `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` na linha em que aplico o estilo a `div`.
O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estar a misturar métodos nativos com métodos do jQuery.

Se quiseres usar jQuery usa o `.each()` se quiseres usar nativo ou usas `[0]` em cada objecto jQuery ou o `document.querySelectorAll`.

Para além disso acho que tens um erro no segundo loop, que é desnecessário pois nunca usas o `y`.

Sugiro usares assim o [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) e [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) para trocar a primeira coleção que o jQuery dá numa array, e depois usares o [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.filter/) para ficares só com os elementos que queres, onde podes aplicar o css que queres.

```js
var evento = $(".day");
var dias = $(".item").map(function () {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get(); // assim ficas com uma array nativa

evento.filter(function (i) {
    return dias.indexOf(this.innerHTML) != -1;
}).css('backgroundColor', "#999");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>...
    <div class="item">31</div>
</div>
<div class="dias-cadastrados">
    <div class="day">4</div>
    <div class="day">21</div>...</div>
```

**Exemplo no jsFiddle também: http://jsfiddle.net/b6hb2443/**

Comment: O seu algoritmo está colorindo o fundo das divs com a  classe day, no entanto preciso que ele mude a cor das div com a classe item que correspondam ao número que está escrito nas divs com a classe day. Podes corrigir isso?

Comment: @JoãoPauloSaragossa é assim que queres: http://jsfiddle.net/b6hb2443/1/ ? nesse caso é só trocar as classes.

Comment: Muito obrigado!